# I want to click on tkinter entry to bind even to return three difference values to entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to click on tkinter entry to change it's value to three values on each click, Present, Leave, Absent, means how event function will return difference values each time , on first click, Present, next click Absent, next click Leave, and then back Present

I will be vary thankful for your kind support :)

Comment: What code do you have now, what solutions have you tried and what specific part is giving you problems?

Comment: Why don't you just use `ttk.Combobox` or `tk.OptionMenu` instead?

Comment: Please include your code and we can help more. But here's a hint: you can use `.configure` to change elements of a tkinter object, including the text.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out any better method. I hope it's good enough. If it's not what you are expecting, let me know in the comment (I'm not sure if I understood you correctly).

```
import tkinter as tk


def handle_click(event):
    if entry.get() == '':
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, 'Present')
    elif entry.get() == 'Present':
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, 'Leave')
    elif entry.get() == 'Leave':
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, 'Absent')
    elif entry.get() == 'Absent':
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, '')

    print(event)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry.bind("<1>", handle_click)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cycle()` from `itertools` module and `next()` function to cycle the three values and bind `<Button-1>` event to change the content of the `Entry`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle

values = cycle(('Present', 'Leave', 'Absent'))

root = tk.Tk()

e_var = tk.StringVar()
# create a Entry that can be changed via mouse click only
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e_var, state='disabled', disabledforeground='black')
entry.pack()
# bind mouse left click to update the Entry from the cycle list
entry.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: e_var.set(next(values)))

root.mainloop()
```